# Restful Service with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to integration a restful interface with Spring Integration. I'm fairly new to Spring Integration and don't really know where to start. The goal is that the restful interface is polled regularly and then a Spring Batch job is automatically started with the new data. Is there somewhere a good example of how to do that? Where is a good point to start? I would like to implement this with Spring DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntegrationFlows.from(// MessageSource to generate request //
                          , e -> e.poller(...))
                .handle(Http(outboundGateway(...))
                .transform(// to JobLaunchRequest //)
                .handle(// JobLaunchingRequestHandler //)
                .handle(// JobExecutionResult //)
                .get();
```

Refer to the [Spring Integration Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) for information about configuring the HTTP gateway and concepts of transformers, message handlers, and the `spring-batch-integration` project (part of `spring-batch`) for `JobLaunchingRequestHandler` etc.